# how do I create a graph in excel spanning the y axis

Tags: excel, graph, vba

I am working with excel and looking to create a graph the same as the following

[image]

See how the y axis has values either side of it - I am wondering how I would create such a graph in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

- prepare your data so that males have negative numbers and females have positive numbers
- insert a clustered bar chart
- format the data series and set the overlap to 100%, set the column width by setting the gap as you please
- add labels to both series
- format the labels for males and set the nubmer format like this: #.##0;#.##0 (this makes the - disappear from the data labels)
- format the axis and set the number format just like you did for the male series
- if needed also reverse the plot order on the axis

Here's the end result:
[image]